# Can I recover a BTRFS RAID disk that was partly overwritten?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid-1, btrfs

I've had a BTRFS RAID set consisting of three (dissimilar) disks for some time now, and it's worked fine.

Unfortunately, due to an unwise experiment on my part, a rogue Windows 7 install dvd added a partition to one of the disks (okay, actually to two of the disks, on two different attempts).  Is there any way I can repair the disk(s)?  The partitions are fairly small, 100MB on a 2TB disk and 100MB on a 4TB disk.  The third disk (also 4TB) is undamaged.

I've tried "sudo btrfs rescue chunk-recover  /dev/sda" but that didn't fix things.  I've also tried "sudo btrfs check /dev/sda" but haven't yet tried to do a repair, for fear of making things worse.

I can work on a "dd" image of the 2TB disk, but I don't have any place to image the 4TB disk to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Step-by-step, or even just pointers to appropriate information, please!